# How to solve this error in xticks(missing) of scatter plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

A scatter plot was plotted using matplotlib as below

```
    pl.title('Test Case 2.1')
    pl.scatter(df2['Cross Section'],df2['Distance'])
    pl.xlabel('Radar cross section [dBsm]')

    pl.xlim([-35, -45])
    pl.ylim(0, 65)

    pl.ylabel('Distance [m]')
    pl.xticks(np.arange(-35, -45,5))
    pl.yticks(np.arange(0, 63, 5))
    pl.grid()
    pl.show()
```

The x axis is missing the limits and xticks.The image is attached[image]
How to solve this?

Comment: Just remove the lines ` pl.xlim([-35, -45])` and `pl.xticks(np.arange(-35, -45, 5))`.  Note that your question is hard to answer without reproducible test data and that `np.arange(-35, -45,5)` is an empty array.  `np.arange(-45, -35, 5)` would be `[-45, -40]` which would also look suspicious.

Comment: @JohanC if i add only pl.xticks([-35,-45]),iw will work but i need in x axis as -35,-40,-45 with grids

Comment: `np.arange(-45, -30, 5)` would be `-35,-40,-45 `.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in radars, so I'm going to assume you know what you are doing. Specifically, with `pl.xlim([-35, -45])` you are setting a greater (absolute) value on the left, decreasing towards the right.

Now, to customize the xticks you are going to use:

```
plt.xticks(np.flip(np.arange(-45, -35, 1)))
```

It's left to you do decompose the previous command and see what each part is doing.

Comment: i added the code but still the x axis has same problem

Comment: Check your code. Did you replaced your old line with mine?

Comment: yeah..replaced this *pl.xticks(np.arange(-35, -45,5))* with your line of code but it didn't worked

Comment: which matplotlib version are you using?

Comment: Note that `np.flip()` doesn't make a difference here, as `plt.xticks()` will sort the values anyway.